# Android Select query with two parameters

Tags: android, sql

Does anyone know how to make this work, I’ve never tried it so I’m not sure where to start really. The calling code is happy to send two parameters but the query is not happy and wants me to remove  + " AND BeachFK=?", args2

```
public String getFacilityDetail(String F_ID, String B_ID) {
    String[] args1 = {F_ID};
    String[] args2 = {B_ID};

    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT FacilityDescription FROM BeachFacility WHERE FacilityFK=?", args1 + " AND BeachFK=?", args2);
    if(c.moveToNext()){
        return(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FacilityDescription")));
    }
    c.close();
    return F_ID;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways:

```
rawQuery("SELECT FacilityDescription FROM BeachFacility WHERE FacilityFK=? AND BeachFK=?",new String[]{F_ID, B_ID});
```

or:

```
rawQuery("SELECT FacilityDescription FROM BeachFacility WHERE FacilityFK='" + F_ID + "' AND BeachFK='" + B_ID + "'", null);
```

Comment: Thanks all for such quick answers, for me it's knock off time, tired! I was not expecting anything untill tommorow and now I can rest easy tonight thanks to you guys. guilliume, both you ways worked! cheers, still learning Mike!